# OpenCV & OpenCVSharp Setup

Tags: opencv

Tried numerous times to compile this correctly but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

I have the latest SVN checkout of both OpenCV and OpenCVSharp. I use CMake to build my solution for OpenCV (Using the x64 Visual Studio 2010 configuration) then compile it in Visual C++ Express 2010.

After that I go on to making a build for OpenCVSharp using Cmake again, but I get an error saying I'm messing OpenCV dll's.

Additionally when I first open OpenCV in VC++, I get a warning saying it doesn't support solution folder. Not sure if that makes a difference here.

**Compile environment:** Windows 7 x64

**Cmake (OpenCV Build Log)**

```
Found Windows SDK v7.1: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\
Could NOT find Qt4 (missing:  QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY) 
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "4.1")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.0")

General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.9 =====================================

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 6.1 x86
    CMake:                       2.8.8
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 10 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1600

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                cl
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4  /EHa /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4  /EHa /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  cl
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3   /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi    /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3   /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi    /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi  /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /STACK:10000000 /machine:x64   /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /STACK:10000000 /machine:x64   /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    Precompiled headers:         YES

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib nonfree legacy gpu photo stitching ts videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 androidcamera java ocl python

  GUI: 
    QT 4.x:                      NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.6)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.9)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.1)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     NO

  Video I/O:
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      codec:                     YES (ver 53.61.100)
      format:                    YES (ver 53.32.100)
      util:                      YES (ver 51.35.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.100)
      gentoo-style:              YES
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    XIMEA:                       NO

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Clp:                     NO

  Python:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Documentation:
    Build Documentation:         NO
    Sphinx:                      NO
    PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    Examples:                    NO

  Install path:                  C:/SourceCode/Makes/OpenCV/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              C:/SourceCode/Makes/OpenCV
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

**Visual C++ Express 2010 (OpenCV Compilation Log)**
**Note: Was too big to post the whole thing.**

```
Visual C++ Express (2010)

1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Checking Build System
...
...
59>  Build all projects
61>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
61>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 55 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 6 skipped ==========
```

**CMakes output when i try to build OpenCVSharp:**

```
Found Windows SDK v7.1: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 Win64
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 Win64 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 Win64
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 Win64 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindOpenCV.cmake:96 (message):
  !!!No OpenCV library found!!!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  OpenCvSharpExtern/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something as simple as your OpenCV .dll's not being in the path. You didn't mention that in your post, did you set your path after compile so that the folder with the .dll's is in it?